# String or binary data would be truncated in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Here is my table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contacts]
(
    [contact_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [c_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [c_number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [c_mail] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [c_address] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [c_date_added] [date] NOT NULL
);
```

and insert query

```
INSERT INTO contacts (user_id, c_name, c_number, c_mail, c_address, c_date_added) 
VALUES (1, 'Aman', '9855', 'aman', 'Gidd', '2014');
```

I am getting this error.

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Please help.

Comment: I tried your exact script in management studio and didn't get an error, could the issue be comewhere else ?

Comment: but i m getting this after execution.  Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: After execution ? I don't understand, how could you get an error before executing ? Are you sure you are inserting into the same table. Try insert dbo.contacts.... instead

Comment: it works.. i re-type query and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query works fine. Just check Below

```
CREATE TABLE #contacts(
[contact_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[c_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[c_number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[c_mail] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[c_address] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[c_date_added] [date] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #contacts (user_id, c_name, c_number, c_mail, c_address, c_date_added) VALUES
(1, 'Aman', '9855', 'aman', 'Gidd', '2014-12-22');


SELECT * FROM #contacts
```